# Is there a proverb/saying which means “good people are always treated terribly and unfairly"?

Tags: idiom-requests, popular-refrains, proverbs, proverb-requests

In English, is there a proverb/saying  that means

> good people are always treated terribly and unfairly  ?

Comment: There's "Nice guys finish last," but that may not be what you are looking for,

Comment: And there's "No good deed goes unpunished."

Comment: @Xanne That's the aphorism that I was trying to recall (by Clare Boothe Luce). You should make it into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Xanne's **no good deed goes unpunished**, which means:

> Beneficial actions often go unappreciated or are met with outright
>   hostility. If they are appreciated, they often lead to additional
>   requests.

I have also found: **eaten bread is soon forgotten**

> (Ireland) Kind deeds or favours are often forgotten by the
>   beneficiary/beneficiaries once they have been done.

**example:**

> Promised increases in productivity following previous pay rises never
>   materialised -- as eaten bread is soon forgotten -- but we'll be
>   paying for the crumbs for a long time to come.